# ng Serve suddenly giving Error: export 'ɵa' (imported as 'i8') was not found in error

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, npm-package

I'm working on a local custom library. I've been testing locally by packing a `tgz`. I haven't had issues but now I get

`Error: export 'ɵa' (imported as 'i8') was not found in 'ngx-filepond' (possible exports: FilePondComponent, FilePondModule, registerPlugin)`

This error is not directly against the library I'm working on as `ngx-filepond` isn't in that library and a dependent. I've run `npm cache clear --force` and even restarted my machine.

I was getting this early on and reordered the local library to a different spot in the modules import. That seemed to fix it but now it's back.

Comment: I've also deleted the lock file and the node_modules directory. Before running `npm i` still get the error.